# In Rails 4 is an -able model still necessary or could I use a many-to-many relationship as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database

Say I have an Article model and a Tag model (and I don't want to use a gem for tagging), how would I build the database relationship between the two?

One way to do it is you connect the two models through a third model Taggable. You'd be using a `has_many :tags, through: :taggable` and a `has_many :articles, through: :taggable` relationship.

This makes perfect sense and I am more than sure this is the only way to connect two complex models together when you look at the issue from a practical standpoint, with Rails and database-workings in mind.

I was just wondering if Rails has a less verbose way of doing this (even though the effect might be the same and you need an extra model connecting the id's of the two together).

Many-to-many, would that work? I think this causes problems. If there isn't any other way then this isn't a big problem, an -able intermediary isn't that inelegant. I was just wondering.

Comment: Yes I think this is the most straightforward approach.  This is a many-to-many relationship, so setting it up with `has_many`/`through:` with a join model makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, I have been busy designing something like this for a db myself and also have come to think so. You can add your answer so I can make it the answer.